# Lombok-related errors on Visual Studio Code with the extension installed

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, lombok

I have decided I had enough of Eclipse's slowness and just moved everything to VSCode. I installed the java extension package as well as the Lombok extension.

My project worked perfectly fine in Eclipse and, although it does **run** fine, VSCode is finding *thousands* of errors obviously related to not finding the getter/setter methods that Lombok generates. My solution consists of two projects that both depend on a class library (the third project) which has a dependency for Lombok registered.

How can I get rid of these errors / make Lombok work properly in VSCode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like my issue was loading the 3 projects into my workspace before installing the Lombok plugin.  I have removed the projects from my workspace and opened them again and the errors are gone.

Comment: +1 from me, it is also possible (now) to right click the pom.xml files and choose "Update project configuration" rather than removing the projects and re-adding them.

Answer (score 1):

here the other way to clean the getter/setter errors :

- under **"Java Projects"** section -> click "**...**"
- Click **"Clean Workspace"**
- wait the clean up process

it will reload the code and no more getter/setter errors

Answer (score 0):

The above works but of course make sure you have the VS Code lombok plugin installed.

1. press Ctrl + Shift + X to open the extension manager.
2. Type lombok to find the plugin, and click install.
3. Reload VS Code.